# Return multiple PHP variables from SQL query using AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to send data using AJAX to a PHP page (which queries a database)  and return specific values. I then will display the results.

I've found several examples on how to pass data using AJAX. This is not my problem. It's how to get the multiple results from a SQL query back to the original page.

**page2.php**

```
$prod01 = $_REQUEST['prod01'];
$prod02 = $_REQUEST['prod02'];

$cost01 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `cost`,`cost2` FROM `info` WHERE `blah`='".$prod01."'"));
$cost02 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `cost`,`cost2` FROM `info` WHERE `blah`='".$prod02."'"));

$getcost01 = $qty01 * $cost01[0];
$getcost02 = $qty02 * $cost02[0];

$foo = array('result01' => $getcost01, 'result02' => $getcost02);
echo json_encode($foo);
```

**page1.php**

```
var prod01 = $("#prod01").val();
var prod02 = $("#prod02").val();


$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "page2.php",
dataType: 'json',  
data : { prod01 : 'pro01', prod02 : 'prod02'},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
  $('.showit01').text(result.result01);
  $('.showit02').text(result.result02);
}
});
```

The result of the above is:

```
$getcost01
$getcost02
```

Not the expected SQL result from database.

When I navigate to "/page2.php?prod01=ABC&prod02=DEF" it displays as expected:

```
{"result01":"100","result2":"200"}
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: You know you can do this with just one query, right?

Comment: Also, that sucks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @JayBlanchard Everything works up to the point of adding the variable.

Comment: @AbraCadaver example code in the question. I tried to stretch everything out so I wasn't missing anything. (And i'm a bit of a newbie...)

Comment: `When I navigate to "/page1.php?prod01=1&prod02=2" it displays as expected:`  Are you sure you don't mean `"/page2.php?prod01=1&prod02=2"`

Comment: Sorry, your life is going to suck if you query the database like that.  Check the link.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get that JSON result. `$getcost01` is an array, not a single value. The PHP script needs to use `$getcost01['thing1']` to get a number.

Comment: There's no way the script could be returning the variable names, that would only happen if you quoted the variable in the array assignment, just like in the original version of your previous question.

Comment: You're obviously editing your script before posting it here, to change variable names. But when you do that, it looks like you're editing away the problem. Post the real code without any editing, and we might be able to figure out what's really wrong.

Comment: I don't see how you got $qty01 and $qty02 equal to anything, but I believe it should be like this inside ajax:    data : { prod01 : pro01, prod02 : prod02},

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was an issue with the ajax. I changed

```
data : { prod01 : 'pro01', prod02 : 'prod02'},
```

to

```
var dataString = 'prod01='+ prod01 +'&prod02='+ prod02;

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "page2.php?",
dataType: 'json',  
data : dataString ,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
  $('.showit01').text(result.result01);
  $('.showit02').text(result.result02);
  }
});
```

I'm assuming my ajax was not formatted properly? I can't explain it.